# How do I call a function in a JavaScript file?

Tags: forms, javascript

I have included a javascript in the module "myid" I've been developing in drupal by using this code:

```
function myid_init() {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path("module", "myid") . "js/myid.js");   
}
```

This is my Javascript file "myid.js":

```
function myid_js_start(){
    alert("hello world");
}
```

Below is the code that creates a button that invokes an alert function:

```
$form['add_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => 'Take a picture',
    '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'myid_js_start()'),    
);
```

I dont know where did I go wrong. The button shows up but doesn't fire any alert function. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Standard question: have you cleared your cache? Have you tried specifying that the function is javascript as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032365/add-an-onclick-attribute-to-login-submit-button-in-drupal-7

Comment: I always clear the cache, everytime I make changes.

Comment: Sadly there are too many who post here that do not know to do that, therefore it is helpful to include that fact in your question =)

Answer (score 1):

Try to write JS in drupal way like this:

```
(function($) {

    Drupal.behaviors.xyzModule = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {


//            $('.test', context).click(function() {
//                $(this).next('ul').toggle('show');
//            });

//myid_js_start();
            function myid_js_start() {
                alert("hello world");
                //console.log(' Hello');
            }

        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

For More info visit [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path("module", "myid") . "js/myid.js");
```

Needs to be:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path("module", "myid") . "/js/myid.js");
```

Note the forward slash before the path to the js file